# Bubbles animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation

I want to make to bubbles animation widget in flutter but, i don't know this is exist or how can write it

like this animation

[image: bubbles animation]

Comment: Try - Animated Backgrounds for Flutter plugin https://pub.dev/packages/animated_background

Comment: No, i want this animation, that plugin is another animation!

Answer (score 6):

I write this widget for you, use it like this:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Bubbles extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _BubblesState();
  }
}

class _BubblesState extends State<Bubbles> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  List<Bubble> bubbles;
  final int numberOfBubbles = 200;
  final Color color = Colors.amber;
  final double maxBubbleSize = 10.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialize bubbles
    bubbles = List();
    int i = numberOfBubbles;
    while (i > 0) {
      bubbles.add(Bubble(color, maxBubbleSize));
      i--;
    }

    // Init animation controller
    _controller = new AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1000), vsync: this);
    _controller.addListener(() {
      updateBubblePosition();
    });
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomPaint(
        foregroundPainter:
            BubblePainter(bubbles: bubbles, controller: _controller),
        size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
      ),
    );
  }

  void updateBubblePosition() {
    bubbles.forEach((it) => it.updatePosition());
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class BubblePainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<Bubble> bubbles;
  AnimationController controller;

  BubblePainter({this.bubbles, this.controller});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size canvasSize) {
    bubbles.forEach((it) => it.draw(canvas, canvasSize));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class Bubble {
  Color colour;
  double direction;
  double speed;
  double radius;
  double x;
  double y;

  Bubble(Color colour, double maxBubbleSize) {
    this.colour = colour.withOpacity(Random().nextDouble());
    this.direction = Random().nextDouble() * 360;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.radius = Random().nextDouble() * maxBubbleSize;
  }

  draw(Canvas canvas, Size canvasSize) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = colour
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    assignRandomPositionIfUninitialized(canvasSize);

    randomlyChangeDirectionIfEdgeReached(canvasSize);

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(x, y), radius, paint);
  }

  void assignRandomPositionIfUninitialized(Size canvasSize) {
    if (x == null) {
      this.x = Random().nextDouble() * canvasSize.width;
    }

    if (y == null) {
      this.y = Random().nextDouble() * canvasSize.height;
    }
  }

  updatePosition() {
    var a = 180 - (direction + 90);
    direction > 0 && direction < 180
        ? x += speed * sin(direction) / sin(speed)
        : x -= speed * sin(direction) / sin(speed);
    direction > 90 && direction < 270
        ? y += speed * sin(a) / sin(speed)
        : y -= speed * sin(a) / sin(speed);
  }

  randomlyChangeDirectionIfEdgeReached(Size canvasSize) {
    if (x > canvasSize.width || x < 0 || y > canvasSize.height || y < 0) {
      direction = Random().nextDouble() * 360;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this in a way that supports bubble collision?

Comment: With this method, it would not be possible to do what you want to happen, for this you have to define an object for each bubble and take its characteristics with the characteristics you see and execute animation when X and Y two objects become one.